# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql

i failed to select data in my php code
this is my code

home.php

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
<?php foreach (App::getInstance()->getTable('Article')->last() as $post) :?> 
       <h2> <a href="<?= $post->url; ?>"><?= $post->titre; ?></a></h2>
       <p><em><?= $post->categorie; ?></em></p>
       <p><?= $post->extrait; ?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
```

articleTable.php

```
<?php
namespace app\Tables;
use core\Tables\Table;

class ArticleTable extends Table{
    public function last(){
        return $this->query('select *from articles');
    }
}
```

app.php

```
<?php
use core\config;
use core\Database\mySQLDatabase;

class App{

    private static $_instance;
    private $db_instance;
    public static function getInstance(){
        if(is_null(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance = new App();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
        }
    public function getTable($name){
        $class_name = '\\app\\Tables\\' . ucfirst($name) . 'Table';
        return new $class_name($this->getDb());
    }
    public function getDb(){
        $config = Config::getInstance(ROOT . '\config\config.php');
        if(is_null($this->db_instance)){
$this->db_instance = new MySQLDatabase($config->get('db_name'),$config->get('db_user'),$config->get('db_pass'),$config->get('db_host'));
        }
        return $this->db_instance;
    }
}
```

the programme show me this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\phpoo(1)\pages\articles\home.php on line 7 
>   Call Stack
>   TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0006252616{main}( )..\index.php:0 20.0019307472
>   require( 'C:\wamp\www\phpoo(1)\pages\articles\home.php' )..\index.php:23 "

Can anybody show me what is wrong?

Comment: What PHP framework are you using? How is home.php called/included? Which line in home.php is line 7? The error is saying that one of the variables in home.php isn't an object.

Comment: i'm not use any framework this is php oop .. the line 7 is :  
<?php foreach (App::getInstance()->getTable('Article')->last() as $post) :?>

Answer (score 0):

`$post` may not be an object like that. Try indexing into it as an array maybe like `$post['extrait']`